# Como pegar palavras e salvar em uma string?

Tags: java, string

Como eu faço para salvar palavras que eu recebo em uma *string* nova?

```
gravarArq.println(token.getLexeme() + "_" + token.getPOSTag() + "_" + token.getFeatures());
```

Como pegar o que vem do `token.getPOSTag()` e salvar todas as palavras que vem dele em uma *string* nova?

```
for (org.cogroo.text.Token token : sentence.getTokens()) { // lista de tokens
    token.getStart(); token.getEnd(); // caracteres onde o token comeca e termina
    token.getLexeme(); // o texto do token (palavra que ele separa e pega exp: "clinico"
    token.getLemmas(); // um array com os possiveis lemas para o par lexeme+postag
    token.getPOSTag(); // classe morfologica de acordo com o contexto("coloca "prp, adj,n(noun))
    token.getFeatures(); // genero, numero, tempo etc
    contadorTokens++;
    System.out.println(token.getLexeme() + "_" + token.getPOSTag() + "_" + token.getFeatures());// imprime a palavra com o tag
      gravarArq.println(token.getLexeme() + "_" + token.getPOSTag() + "_" + token.getFeatures());
    //System.out.println(token.getLexeme());
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Poderia esclarecer qual é a sua dúvida? Em que parte do código exatamente que está tendo problemas? Pelo que entendi é só pegar o que vem do `token.getPOSTag()` e jogar em uma nova variável, não é? Aproveite e faça um [tour] pelo site e confira o guia de [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi, acho que é isso.

// instanciação poo

```
String val = new String(token.getPOSTag());
```

// declaração e instanciação (mais prático)

```
String val = token.getPOSTag();
```

Mas se seu atributo token.getPOSTag() tiver mais de 1 valor após aquela varredura do for, você vai precisar de uma lista.

```
ArrayList<String> listaTokens = new ArrayList<String>();

for (org.cogroo.text.Token token : sentence.getTokens()) { // lista de tokens
    token.getStart(); token.getEnd(); // caracteres onde o token comeca e termina
    token.getLexeme(); // o texto do token (palavra que ele separa e pega exp: "clinico"
    token.getLemmas(); // um array com os possiveis lemas para o par lexeme+postag
    listaTokens.add(token.getPOSTag()); // classe morfologica de acordo com o contexto("coloca "prp, adj,n(noun))
    token.getFeatures(); // genero, numero, tempo etc
    contadorTokens++;
    System.out.println(token.getLexeme() + "_" + token.getPOSTag() + "_" + token.getFeatures());// imprime a palavra com o tag
      gravarArq.println(token.getLexeme() + "_" + token.getPOSTag() + "_" + token.getFeatures());
    //System.out.println(token.getLexeme());
}
```